# Any script to notify when there is no write activity in folder

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, fswatch

I am trying to come up with a nice and easy way of detecting when there has not been any write activity in a folder I'd like to watch.

Basically, what I'd like to have is something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

# colored red text (error)
function errorMsg () {
  echo '\033[0;31m'"$1"'\033[0m'
}

# check for folder to monitor argument
if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]
then
  errorMsg "add experiment (folder) to monitor for activity!"
exit
fi

# time out time, 3 minutes
TIMEOUT_TIME=180
LAST_CHECKED=0

function refreshTimer () {
  # when called, check seconds since epoch
  CURRENT_TIME=date +%s

  if [ CURRENT_TIME - LAST_CHECKED > TIMEOUT_TIME ]
  then
    echo "file write activity halted!" | mail -s "trouble!" "user@provider.ext"
  fi

  LAST_CHECKED=date +%s
}

# set last checked to now.
LAST_CHECKED=date +%s
# start monitoring for file changes, and update timer when new files are being written.
fswatch -r ${1} | refreshTimer
```

but all sorts of bash magic is required I presume, since fswatch is a background task and piping its output creates a subshell.
I would also be in need of some timer logic...
I was thinking something like a setTimeout of which the time argument keeps being added to when there IS activity, but I don't know how to write it all in one script.

Bash, Python, Ruby, anything that can be installed using homebrew on OSX is fine but the simpler the better (so I understand what is happening).

Comment: You need to use `#!/bin/bash` for the hashbang, or remove all the `bash`-only constructs from your script.

Comment: Please clarify what exactly your question is. We won't develop the whole script for you, and AFAIK software recommendations are off topic.

Comment: @chepner I wrote something off the top of my head, using some parts from a different script, but yes, you are right :) @l0b0, I am not sure what you don't understand. My use case is that I run simulations, they put results in a folder (i.e. write operations). This i can watch with ```fswatch``` (installable using homebrew). However, I'd like to know when there has not been any write activity in a while (which indicates something is going wrong). I even tried to show what I want by creating a stub script.. I am not asking about software recommendations. I'm stating that any solution is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following - note that it requires `bash`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# colored red text (error)
function errorMsg () {
  printf '\033[0;31m%s\033[0m\n' "$*" >&2
}

# check for folder to monitor argument
if [[ $# -ne 1 ]]
then
  errorMsg "add experiment (folder) to monitor for activity!"
  exit 2
fi

# time-out: 3 minutes
TIMEOUT_TIME=180

# Read fswatch output as long as it is
# within the timeout value; every change reported
# resets the timer.
while IFS= read -t $TIMEOUT_TIME -d '' -r file; do 
  echo "changed: [$file]"
done < <(fswatch -r -0 "${1}")

# Getting here means that read timed out.
echo "file write activity halted!" | mail -s "trouble!" "user@provider.ext"
```

- `fswatch` *indefinitely* outputs lines to stdout, which must be read *line by line* to take *timely* action on new output.
- `fswatch -0` terminates lines with NULs (zero bytes), which `read` then reads on be one by setting the line delimiter (separator) to an empty string (`-d ''`).
- `< <(fswatch -r -0 "${1}")` provides input via stdin `<` to the `while` loop, where `read` consumes the stdin input one NUL-terminated line at a time.

  - `<(fswatch -r -0 "${1}")` is a [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution) that forms an "ad-hoc file" (technically, a FIFO or named file descriptor) from the output produced by `fswatch -r -0 "${1}"` (which watches folder `${1}`'s subtree (`-r`) for file changes, and reports each terminated with NUL (`-0`)).
  - Since the `fswatch` command runs indefinitely, the "ad-hoc file" will continue to provide input, although typically only intermittently, depending on filesystem activity.
- Whenever the `read` command receives a new line within the timeout period (`-t $TIMEOUT_TIME`), it terminates *successfully* (exit code 0), causing the body of the loop to be executed and then `read` to be invoked *again*.

  - Thus, whenever a line has been received, the timeout period is effectively reset, because the new `read` invocation starts over with the timeout period.
  - By contrast, if the timeout period expires before another line is received, `read` terminates *unsuccessfully* - with a *nonzero* exit code indicating *failure*, which causes the `while` loop to terminate.
- Thus, the code after the loop is only reached when the `read` command times out.

---

**As for your original code**:

Note: Some of the problems discussed could have been detected with the help of [shellecheck.net](http://shellcheck.net)

- `echo '\033[0;31m'"$1"'\033[0m'`

  - `printf` is the better choice when it comes to interpreting escape sequences, since `echo`'s behavior varies across shells and platforms; for instance, running your script with `bash` will *not* interpret them (unless you also add the `-e` option).
- `function refreshTimer ()`

  - The `function` syntax is nonstandard (not POSIX-compliant), so you shouldn't use it with a `sh` shebang line (that's what chepner meant in his comment). On OSX, you can get away with it, because `bash` acts as `sh` and *most* bashisms are still available when run as `sh`, but it wouldn't work on other systems. If you know you'll be running with `bash` anyway, it's better to use a `bash` shebang line.
- `CURRENT_TIME=date +%s`

  - You can't assign the output from commands to a variable by simply placing the command as is on the RHS of the assignment; instead, you need a [command substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution); in the case at hand: `CURRENT_TIME=$(date +%s)` (the older syntax with backticks - `` CURRENT_TIME=`date +%s` `` - works too, but has disadvantages).
- `[ CURRENT_TIME - LAST_CHECKED > TIMEOUT_TIME ]`

  - `>` in `[ ... ]` and bash's `[[ ... ]]` conditionals is *lexical* comparison and the variable names must be `$`-prefixed; you'd have to use an *arithmetic* conditional with your syntax: `(( CURRENT_TIME - LAST_CHECKED > TIMEOUT_TIME ))`
  - As an aside, it's better [better not to use all-uppercase variable names](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_01) in shell programming.
- `fswatch -r ${1} | refreshTimer`

  - `refreshTimer` will not get called until the pipe fills up (the timing of which you won't be able to predict), because you make no attempt to read *line by line*.
  - Even if you fix that problem, the variables inside `refreshTimer` won't be preserved, because `refreshTimer` runs in a *new subshell* every time, due to use of a pipeline (`|`). In `bash`, this problem is frequently worked around by providing input via a [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution) (`<(...)`), which you can see in action in my code above.

Comment: This seems exactly what i want, but I don't see where the timer gets reset? could you elaborate? thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much @mklement0 for your elaborate explanation, and do's and donot's regarding to my really bad shell example script. I still need to get used to the ```while...done``` syntax, although I understand what the script does. This is exactly what I was looking for! If I could +4 this answer I would have done so, for the elaborate explanations and helpful links (4 total).

Comment: @MichaelTrouw: My pleasure; I'm glad it helped. I've rewritten the explanation with respect to the loop - hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Yes, now it's completely clear to me, this is how I thought it would work, providing input to a while loop is something I had not seen before, but it all makes perfect sense!